# Как произвести извлечение PostGIS формата (Geometry) из PostgreSQL правильным образом через NetBeans?

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, orm, postgis

Я использую EclipseLink JPA 2.1. в NetBeans.

1) Установил дополнительное расширение PostGIS в PostgreSQL для работы с геоданными.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) После установки расширения включил его посредством выполнения команд:

```
--Enable PostGIS (includes raster)
create extension postgis;

--Enable Topology
create EXTENTION postgis_topology;
```

3) Создал тестовую таблицу в БД таким образом, чтобы один из столбцов представлял собой тип для работы с геоданными, а именно тип **geometry**.

```
create table test_geometry
(
    id SERIAL primary key,
    geom geometry
);
```

4) Вставил запись:

```
insert into test_geometry(geom) values 
(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON (((37.2201217712901950 55.4673797083167410, 37.2206294563976600 55.4671339498379580, 37.2210500373942210 55.4669302965252980, 37.2210538540889860 55.4669047959040070, 37.2204981033848060 55.4665264557449970, 37.2202299865368930 55.4663440436543520, 37.2201855747514680 55.4663418761293410, 37.2197648368431120 55.4665456159516950, 37.2192569958389540 55.4667913705081190, 37.2189949015397660 55.4669183150927980, 37.2189129256524250 55.4668625271055760, 37.2192164284513110 55.4667154679358630, 37.2195015233931980 55.4665776174088240, 37.2198307228985710 55.4664181304612070, 37.2201035983734490 55.4662860889336290, 37.2201072575144000 55.4662605879777860, 37.2194144788170220 55.4657893230126150, 37.2194414878181950 55.4657707919189490, 37.2195131610941060 55.4657410457660020, 37.2195943494814540 55.4657962028061600, 37.2197161312114630 55.4658791179051680, 37.2212568609412460 55.4669273549825590, 37.2209026081465520 55.4670972976899180, 37.2205032838429660 55.4672906696043170, 37.2200316108871690 55.4675189049915290, 37.2199494741848800 55.4674631173389510, 37.2201217712901950 55.4673797083167410)))'));
```

5) Запустил Netbeans:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

6) Создал новый проект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

7) Создал ORM-модель таблицы, которую я создал в пункте 3.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

8) В итоге получил такой класс:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication6;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author ramze
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_geometry")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "TestGeometry.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TestGeometry t")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "TestGeometry.findById", query = "SELECT t FROM TestGeometry t WHERE t.id = :id")})
public class TestGeometry implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "geom")
    private Object geom;

    public TestGeometry() {
    }

    public TestGeometry(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Object getGeom() {
        return geom;
    }

    public void setGeom(Object geom) {
        this.geom = geom;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof TestGeometry)) {
            return false;
        }
        TestGeometry other = (TestGeometry) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "javaapplication6.TestGeometry[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

9) Для того, чтобы производить какое-либо взаимодействие со своей таблицей, я должен выполнить эту операцию:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JavaApplication6PU");
```

10) После выполнения пункта №9, я получаю исключение следующего рода:

```
Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [JavaApplication6PU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7164] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.Object] for the attribute [geom] on the entity class [class javaapplication6.TestGeometry] is not a valid type for a lob mapping. For a lob of type BLOB, the attribute must be defined as a java.sql.Blob, byte[], Byte[] or a Serializable type. For a lob of type CLOB, the attribute must be defined as a java.sql.Clob, char[], Character[] or String type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at javaapplication6.JavaApplication6.main(JavaApplication6.java:22)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [JavaApplication6PU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7164] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.Object] for the attribute [geom] on the entity class [class javaapplication6.TestGeometry] is not a valid type for a lob mapping. For a lob of type BLOB, the attribute must be defined as a java.sql.Blob, byte[], Byte[] or a Serializable type. For a lob of type CLOB, the attribute must be defined as a java.sql.Clob, char[], Character[] or String type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1954)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1945)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:96)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [JavaApplication6PU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7164] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.Object] for the attribute [geom] on the entity class [class javaapplication6.TestGeometry] is not a valid type for a lob mapping. For a lob of type BLOB, the attribute must be defined as a java.sql.Blob, byte[], Byte[] or a Serializable type. For a lob of type CLOB, the attribute must be defined as a java.sql.Clob, char[], Character[] or String type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:230)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7164] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.Object] for the attribute [geom] on the entity class [class javaapplication6.TestGeometry] is not a valid type for a lob mapping. For a lob of type BLOB, the attribute must be defined as a java.sql.Blob, byte[], Byte[] or a Serializable type. For a lob of type CLOB, the attribute must be defined as a java.sql.Clob, char[], Character[] or String type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.invalidTypeForLOBAttribute(ValidationException.java:1132)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.converters.LobMetadata.process(LobMetadata.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processLob(MappingAccessor.java:1707)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.BasicAccessor.processLob(BasicAccessor.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processMappingConverter(MappingAccessor.java:1771)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processMappingValueConverter(MappingAccessor.java:1796)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.BasicAccessor.process(BasicAccessor.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataDescriptor.processMappingAccessors(MetadataDescriptor.java:1536)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.processMappingAccessors(ClassAccessor.java:1648)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.processMappingAccessors(EntityAccessor.java:1234)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.process(EntityAccessor.java:697)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage2(MetadataProject.java:1793)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1869)
    ... 6 more
C:\Users\ramze\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\debug.xml:83: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, чтобы исправить эту ошибку? Как правильным образом отразить табличное представление, где один из столбцов представляет собой Geometry формат???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем я сам решил эту задачу:

1) Вот моя таблица **test_geometry** в PostgreSQL базе данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Вот мой автоматически сгенерированный ORM Java класс **TestGeometry**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_geometry")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "TestGeometry.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TestGeometry t")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "TestGeometry.findById", query = "SELECT t FROM TestGeometry t WHERE t.id = :id")})
public class TestGeometry implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "geom")    
    private Object geom;

    public TestGeometry() {
    }

    public TestGeometry(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Object getGeom() {
        return geom;
    }

    public void setGeom(Object geom) {
        this.geom = geom;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof TestGeometry)) {
            return false;
        }
        TestGeometry other = (TestGeometry) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "javaapplication6.TestGeometry[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

3) Добавил 3 необходимые библиотеки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4) В автоматически сгенерированном ORM Java классе **TestGeometry** мной вручную были изменены следующие параметры:

Изменил

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "geom")
private Object geom;
public Object getGeom() {
    return geom;
}
public void setGeom(String geom) {
    this.geom = geom;
}
```

на

```
@Column(name = "geom")    
private String geom;
public String getGeom() {
    return geom;
}  
public void setGeom(String geom) {
    this.geom = geom;
}
```

5) В main классе получил координаты следующим образом:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JavaApplication6PU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
TestGeometry test = em.createNamedQuery("TestGeometry.findAll", TestGeometry.class).getSingleResult();
WKTReader reader = new WKTReader();
Geometry geom = reader.read(test.getGeom());        
Coordinate[] coordinates = geom.getCoordinates();

//Распечатаем координаты
for(Coordinate current_coordinate : coordinates)
{
    System.out.println(current_coordinate);
}
```

В итоге получил следующий результат:

```
(37.220121771290195, 55.46737970831674, NaN)
(37.22062945639766, 55.46713394983796, NaN)
(37.22105003739422, 55.4669302965253, NaN)
(37.221053854088986, 55.46690479590401, NaN)
(37.220498103384806, 55.466526455745, NaN)
(37.22022998653689, 55.46634404365435, NaN)
(37.22018557475147, 55.46634187612934, NaN)
(37.21976483684311, 55.466545615951695, NaN)
(37.219256995838954, 55.46679137050812, NaN)
(37.218994901539766, 55.4669183150928, NaN)
(37.218912925652425, 55.466862527105576, NaN)
(37.21921642845131, 55.46671546793586, NaN)
(37.2195015233932, 55.466577617408824, NaN)
(37.21983072289857, 55.46641813046121, NaN)
(37.22010359837345, 55.46628608893363, NaN)
(37.2201072575144, 55.466260587977786, NaN)
(37.21941447881702, 55.465789323012615, NaN)
(37.219441487818195, 55.46577079191895, NaN)
(37.219513161094106, 55.465741045766, NaN)
(37.219594349481454, 55.46579620280616, NaN)
(37.21971613121146, 55.46587911790517, NaN)
(37.221256860941246, 55.46692735498256, NaN)
(37.22090260814655, 55.46709729768992, NaN)
(37.220503283842966, 55.46729066960432, NaN)
(37.22003161088717, 55.46751890499153, NaN)
(37.21994947418488, 55.46746311733895, NaN)
(37.220121771290195, 55.46737970831674, NaN)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

**Дополнительно**: Для нахождения ответа на поставленный мной вопрос, я пользовался следующими ссылками:

[Ссылка 1](https://gis-lab.info/docs/postgis/manual/ch04.html);

[Ссылка 2](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.postgis.PGgeometry);

[Ссылка 3](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=realityforge%2Fgeolatte-geom-jpa%2Fgeolatte-geom-jpa-master%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Frealityforge%2Fjeo%2Fgeolatte%2Fjpa%2FPostgisConverter.java);

[Ссылка 4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146266/understanding-the-format-wkb-from-wkt-and-how-to-convert-the-first-into-the-lat);

[Ссылка 5](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsBinary.html);

[Ссылка 6](https://www.javatips.net/api/spatial-framework-for-hadoop-master/hive/src/main/java/com/esri/hadoop/hive/ST_AsBinary.java#);

[Ссылка 7](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop);

[Ссылка 8](https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java);

[Ссылка 9](https://books.google.ru/books?id=T5okbaR3X2kC&pg=PT134&lpg=PT134&dq=the%20attribute%20must%20be%20defined%20as%20a%20java.sql.Blob,%20byte%5B%5D,%20Byte%5B%5D%20or%20a%20Serializable%20type&source=bl&ots=nkShAQnRdz&sig=ACfU3U1_O6ngU5qVJrNUEe9umkWhZEIKGw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWjOX55avnAhXGxaYKHTZ0BNIQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=the%20attribute%20must%20be%20defined%20as%20a%20java.sql.Blob%2C%20byte%5B%5D%2C%20Byte%5B%5D%20or%20a%20Serializable%20type&f=false);